# backbone paginator multi model in a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, backbone-views

I have a shopping cart app made with Backbone.Paginator.Fluenced and forked with this example; https://github.com/msurguy/laravel-backbone-pagination

I made some small changes;
when you click over an item link, it opens a bootstrap modal window.
The code is below.

```
app.views.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4',
  template: _.template($('#ProductItemTemplate').html()),
  events: {
    'click a.openModal': 'openModal'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.bind('remove', this.remove, this);
  },
  render : function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  openModal : function () {
    var view = new app.views.ModalView({model:this.model});
    view.render();
  }

});
```

and this is my ModalView to show product details in a modal window.

```
app.views.ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#modal-bsbb').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    _.bind(this.render, this);     
  },
  render: function () {
    $('#myModalPop').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: true});
    $('#myModalPop').html(this.template({
      'model':this.model.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  }
 });
```

Everything is fine for above codes.

I decided to optimize this code and wanted some improvements on this.
Firstly I am fetching all product data and send these data to modal windows.
I think i must send only main meta data and must fetch details from these window.

So i made a new Backbone Model and Collection;

```
app.models.ItemDetails = Backbone.Model.extend({});

app.collections.ItemDetails = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.models.ItemDetails,
  dataType: 'json',
  url : "/api/item-details",
  parse: function(response){
    return response.data;
  }
});
```

My api returns JSON :

```
{"data":{"id":8,"title":"Product 8","seo":"product-8","code":"p8","review":"Lorem30"}}
```

My problem is adding multiple models to ModalView;
I tried a lot of example and questions in blogs&forums couldnt find any solve.

I tried a lot of things ($.extend, to set model and model vs..)
to change ModalView and below codes are last position of them;

```
app.views.ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#modal-bsbb').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    _.bind(this.render, this);     
  },
  render: function () {
    var itemDetails = new app.collections.ItemDetails(); // this is new line
    var model2 = itemDetails.fetch(); // this is new line
    $('#myModalPop').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: true});
    $('#myModalPop').html(this.template({
      'model1':this.model.toJSON(),
      'model2':model2.model // this is new line
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
```

I want to add a second model to my underscore template. But cant!

Firstly when i run below codes on chrome developer console it gets an Object;
but couldnt convert as a new model or JSON.

```
  var itemDetails = new app.collections.ItemDetails(); 
  var model2 = itemDetails.fetch(); 
  console.log(model2); // gets fetch data as an object
```

I am afraid I am confused about where the problem exactly is.

Sorry guys I am not a backbone expert and probably I am doing something wrong though I searched a lot about it on the forum. I read about it again and again but I could not solve the problem. Could you please help me. Thank you in advance.

**SOLVE:**

After searchs and by the help of below reply.
I solved my problem.

```
app.views.ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#modal-bsbb').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    _.bind(this.render, this);    
  },
  render: function () {
    var _thisView = this;
    var itemsDetails = new app.collections.ItemsDetails();
    itemsDetails.fetch({
      success:function(data){
        $('#myModalPop').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: true})
        .html(_thisView.template({
          'model1':_thisView.model.toJSON(),
          'model2':data.at(0).toJSON()
        }));
      }});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every request to server using backbone is async, it means that you will not have the returned data immediately after the request, maybe the server still processing the data.

To solve this problem you have 2 ways.

First Way: Callbacks

Inside your Model/Collection

```
GetSomeData:->
    @fetch(
       success:=(data)>
           console.log data // the returned data from server will be avaiable.

    )
```

Second way: Listen for an trigger.
This one it's more elegant using backbone because you don't write callbacks.

Inside Model
    GetSomeData:->
        @fecth()

Inside View

```
initialize:->
    @model = new KindOfModel()
    @model.on "sync", @render, @
```

backbone automatically will trigger some events for you, take a read here.
http://backbonejs.org/#Events

As you're already doing, you'll need to listen to some trigger on the collection too

var itemDetails = new app.collections.ItemDetails(); // this is new line
var model2 = itemDetails.fetch(); // **here is the problem**

Comment: Thanks, i tried first way, after that i get an object, json data in responseText. I couldnt anyway convert this model to jSON for template. but it gives error.